# mySQL auto increment problem: Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, auto-increment, mysql-error-1062

I have a table of emails.

The last record in there for an auto increment id is 3780, which is a legit record. Any new record I now insert is being inserted right there.

However, in my logs I have the occasional:

```
Query FAIL: INSERT INTO mail.messages (timestamp_queue) VALUES (:time);
Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1062
    [2] => Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 1
)
```

Somehow, the autoincrement jumped up to the INT max of 4294967295

Why on god's green earth would this get jumped up so high? I have no inserts with an id field.

The show status for that table, Auto_increment table now reads: 4294967296

How could something like this occur? I realize the id field should perhaps be a big int, but the worry I have is that somehow this thing jumps back up.

Josh

Edit: Update

mysql version 5.0.45 red hat patched

Since I set the id to BIGINT the last few id's look like:

```
3777
3778
3779
3780
4294967295
4294967296
4294967297
4294967298
4294967299
4294967300
```

As you can see, they are incremental, with no gaps (so far). Totally weird.

Comment: What kind of field is :time inserting into?
Are there any clues contained in values of the row whose id is 4294967296?

Comment: What version of mysql? Did you read any of the "about 3,020 for Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 1" results from Google? Have you checked to see if there's any gaps in the current ids? Have you checked to see if there really is a record with id 4294967295? Are you sure your code doesn't do an explicit insert/update on this field to set it to -1? What do you mean by "the last record"? The most recent? The max id? You can read back the current insert id (I can see this in PMA) though I've no idea how to check it. C.

Comment: There IS a single record with 42xxx as the ID, though I have no idea how it got there, right. Its written 7k records over 3 months, and its just now presenting.

I use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, which had a bug involving auto increment a long time ago, but it doesn't track, because there are no gaps in the id's, besides the one SUPER large one.

Comment: timestamp_sent is an INT(10)

There are no clues in the values. They are all complete. I always use prepared statements, so I'm not worried about sql injection. Hmmm.

Comment: I wonder if a field length overwrite could cause something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its still not totally clear to me what happened here, but I thought I'd follow up.

In my persistence engine, I had one type of object with a auto-increment id, and a subclass with a GUID id.

Obviously the two were incompatible. I have a reason to convert the object to its parent and then save it (basically the subclass is an email TEMPLATE that has additional functionality, but when i want to actually SEND the email, I convert it to the parent object and save it to the regular outgoing mail queue). Stupidly, I didn't realize the id formats were different. This resulted in trying to insert a record with a 36 character long string into an int. The string resolved to '0' in the prepared statement and for whatever reason this cause the auto-increment system to WIG OUT and max out the INT auto increment id field on the original table.

Long story short, good thing I was keeping logs.

Josh

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with the exact same number. My problem was that I had the field on `int(10)` when I changed it to `bigint(20)` it solved my problem.

If others are having this problem. Check your field size first. :)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when  you accidentally insert a new record a provide the auto_increment value.

Most of the time that's because you have a column with a similar name and you make a typo that leads to the auto_increment value updated with the one you provided, which is 4294967295 if you provided a string instead of an int.

To solve this:

- delete the record whose PK value is  4294967295,
- check what was the max increment value by running

> ```
> select max(autoincrementColumNameHere) from tableNameHere
> ```

- update your AUTO_INCREMENT value by running

> ```
>  ALTER TABLE tableNameHere AUTO_INCREMENT = (maxValue+1)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

by phpmyadmin simply you can change last id with operations tab of that table

Answer (score 0):

This actually just happened to me too (still not sure why).  On a hunch I did:

```
ALTER TABLE  `{table name here}` AUTO_INCREMENT = {your number here};
FLUSH TABLE `{table name here}`;
```

and it seems to have fixed it.  First I tried just setting the auto increment value first but it went back to 4294967295. Again, not sure why changing the increment value and flushing worked (I'm not a database guy), but I figured I'd post this here as it may help others.

Answer (score -1):

Just change it to a BIGINT and you can create "some" extra new records. A couple of hundred billion... ;)

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me too. The problem is a silly one.

If it receives a `character string` it converts it `0` and if `integer, as in my case, where i was trying to insert a mobile no (in india it's 10 digits and starts with 9 like`9123456789`) into a`int` type column.

However, the limit for `signed int` is `2147483647`.

I tried converting it to `unsigned`, but still the limit is `4294967295`. Thus error "4294967295" something, but when I converted it to `bigint`, which has a limit of `9223372036854775807` (which is more for 10 digit mobile no), it started to accept it.

For the sake of mobile no I converted it to `unsigned` which increased its limit to `18446744073709551615`.